# Why I can't pass class object by reference here?

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
 class Token {
    std::string name; // token name
    int frequency;//frequency
    Vector lines;//lines where the token is present

public:
    //explanations for the methods in the Token.cpp
    Token(std::string tokenname, int linenumber);
    virtual ~Token();
    void newEntry(int &linenumber);
    std::string getName();
    int getFrequency();
    std::string toString();
};
```

And there is an another class

```
class Node {
    Token data;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node(const Token &v);

};
```

In the constructor of node I want to pass a constant reference to the token object. But when I write the method in the cpp file:

```
  Node::Node(const Token &v){
    data = v;
}
```

I get a compiler error:

> ../src/List.cpp: In constructor ‘Node::Node(const Token&)’: ../src/List.cpp:11:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘Token::Token()’  Node::Node(const Token &v){
>                             ^ ../src/List.cpp:11:26: note: candidates are: In file included from ../src/List.h:10:0,
>                    from ../src/List.cpp:8: ../src/Token.h:19:2: note: Token::Token(std::string, int)   Token(std::string tokenname, int linenumber);   ^ ../src/Token.h:19:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided ../src/Token.h:12:7: note: Token::Token(const Token&)  class Token {
>          ^ ../src/Token.h:12:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided make: *** [src/List.o] Error 1

How can I fix this and what causes this problem? I really want to pass the Token reference/

Comment: Read the error messages again, it says there is no default constructor for `Token`. Then search for and read about *constructor initializer lists*.

Comment: Should your node contain a copy of the supplied token or just point to an already existing token?

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? I don't think the linked question answers the OP question the best way.

Comment: This is relatively basic C++. You should read up on the language fundamentals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change implementation like this:

```
Node::Node(const Token &v) : data(v){
}
```

to invoke the right constructor, otherwise the compiler will call default constructor first (which is missing, hence the message), then the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, `Token` need to have a default ctor but it doesn't have. `data` in class `Node` will be initialized by its default ctor first, and then assigned by `operator=` in the ctor of `Node::Node`. You can use ctor initialization list to solve it, the copy ctor of `Token` will be called instead.

```
Node::Node(const Token &v) : data(v) {}
```